# preg_match_all with multilines not working

Tags: php, regex

I have a string `mystring` that contains newlines in it :

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
switch -glob [string tolower [HTTP::host]] {
    "sub1.sub.dom" {
    pool /networkname/hostname_80
    }
    "sub2.sub.dom" {
    pool /anothernetworkname/anotherhostname_80
    }
    default {
         drop 
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to extract the pools from that string using `preg_match_all` but I cant get the wanted result...I'm currently using :

```
preg_match_all('/\/([^"]+)$/m',$mystring,$result);
```

the result is :

```
Array
(
[0] => networkname/hostname_80
    }
[1] => anothernetworkname/anotherhostname_80
    }
    default {
         drop 
    }
}
})
```

I have two questions :

1. Why is the second element of the array is not similar to the first one? considering the fact that I'm using the same regex?
2. how can I get only the pools without the braces and all the stuff behind (the regex should stop matching after the last digit of a line).

thanks.

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('/\bpool\h+\K\S+$/m',$mystring,$result);`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew i think there should be `g` (global. All matches (don't return after first match) also in the end of regex `/\bpool\h+\K\S+$/mg` for global match https://regex101.com/r/FUWdQN/1

Comment: @Noman PHP preg functions do not support `g` modifier. To get the first match `preg_match` is used, `preg_match_all` to match all occurrences.

Comment: ah okay Thank you ^_^

Comment: Maybe `preg_match_all('/\/([^\n"]+)$/m',$mystring,$result);` with `\n` to not  match a newline.

Comment: @Thefourthbird tried it but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just want to extract chunks of non-whitespace chars after a word `pool`, 1+ whitespaces and `/`.

You may use

```
'~\bpool\h+/\K\S+$~m'
```

with `preg_match_all` function in PHP. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FUWdQN/2).

**Details**

- `\bpool` - a whole word `pool` (the next char should be a horizontal whitespace and `\b` is a word boundary)
- `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `/` - a `/` char
- `\K` - match reset operator to discard the text matched so far
- `\S+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace
- `$` - end of line (due to `m` modifier).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/XvgEmx):

```
$re = '~\bpool\h+\K/\S+$~m';
$str = "when HTTP_REQUEST {\nswitch -glob [string tolower [HTTP::host]] {\n    \"sub1.sub.dom\" {\n    pool /networkname/hostname_80\n    }\n    \"sub2.sub.dom\" {\n    pool /anothernetworkname/anotherhostname_80\n    }\n    default {\n         drop \n    }\n}\n}";
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => networkname/hostname_80
    [1] => anothernetworkname/anotherhostname_80
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wiktor regex is right but it missing `.` after space `\S`, see [**preg_match_all Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22959f6022ff12eea491cd42a840d339e2b2b119)

```
/\bpool\h+\K\S.+$/m
```

Regex Explanation:

1. \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W) pool
   matches the characters pool literally (case sensitive)
2. \h+ matches any horizontal whitespace character (equal to
   [[:blank:]])

   - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
3. \K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously
   consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
4. \S matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
5. .+ matches any character (except for line terminators)
6. Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
7. $ asserts position at the end of a line

**Global pattern flags**

9. m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of
   each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: had the same result with your expression and wiktor's. thanks for your contribution +1.